# Array of Arrays - writing to File problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

and again my array of arrays ... I try to improve my app performance by buffering arrays on file for later reuse.

I have an NSMutableArray that contains about 30 NSMutableArrays with NSNumber, NSDate and NSString Objects.

I try to write the file using this call:

```
bool result = [myArray writeToFile:[fileMethods 
                                    getFullPath:[NSString 
                                                 stringWithFormat:@"iEts%@.arr", 
                                                 [aDate shortDateString]]] 
                       atomically:NO];
```

=> result = FALSE.

The Path method is:

```
+ (NSString *) getFullPath:(NSString *)forFileName {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:forFileName];
}
```

and the aDate call returns a shortDateString with ddMMyy.

The NSLog

```
NSLog(@"%@", [fileMethods getFullPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iEts%@.arr", 
                                                [aDate shortDateString]]]);
```

on the path generation returns:

```
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/86729620-EC1D-4C10-A799-0C638BB27933/Documents/iEts010510.arr
```

FURTHER:

- It must have something to do with the
  Array of Arrays, since I also write 3
  further simple arrays (containing
  NSStrings) that all succeed.
- The Array of Arrays gets generated using the addObject method

Any ideas what could cause the trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got any NSNulls in your arrays anywhere?  I don't think they count as plist objects and so would cause the write to fail.

Comment: I had empty string in the array, but when I test filled them the array store still failed - situation unchanged

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the write to file uses object archiving hence some objects in your array of arrays can't be archived.

Comment: Property list, not object archiving.  Same general effect, though.

Comment: hmm, I followed your lead and started test writing the sub-arrays. It seems that those with empty NSStrings fail to write. Adding a single space character doesn't help either ....

Comment: don't get it. neither NSNumber, NSDate, nor NSString are reported as troublemakers. Filling my empty strings with some text also doesn't change anything .... weird. In my subarray enumeration it writes the subarray when 1 object was attached, from the second object onwards it fails ...